# JQuery UI Drop Disable on some elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jsplumb

I have a jQuery UI draggable code, that i write with jslumb.

**the problem is user can drop circle on another circle, i don't want to allow it, 
simply i need to revert if the user drag and drop circle on another circle.**

i write some codes for this. but thi not working for me, it always revert the dropped circle.
here is my example url

http://webxtreams.net/demoprofiles004/circledragger.html

here is js code i run on fire bug

```
$(".circle").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$(".circle").droppable({
    accept: function(el) {        
        return el.hasClass('.circle');
    }
});
```

please help me to do that.

have another little question -  can we track the reverting event on this, i need to repaint the lines when reverting the circle :)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QGKC/)**

First set the options for your draggable event:

```
    var revTest=false;
    var options = {
                revert: function(socketObj){
                if(socketObj === false){ //when circle is not over circle 
                    revTest = false; //we don't want to revert
                    return false;
                }else{    //when circle is over circle
                     revTest = true; //revert the action
                     return true;
                }
            },
            scope:"Circle",
            stop: function(e , ui){
                   if(revTest === true){
                      alert("Circle cannot overlay Circle");
                      jsPlumb.repaint(this.id); // needed if the element is associated with jsPlumb endpoints or connections
                   }
            }
        };
```

Now include the options to your draggable element:

```
jsPlumb.draggable($("#Circle2"),options);
```

For the droppable event:

```
$("#Circle1").droppable({scope:"Circle"});
```